# PHP form sends email WITH field titles, WITHOUT collected Data

Tags: php, forms

I Have been trying to get a Php script working for the better part of a week :-/.  I've kept it super simple, and I still cannot seem to figure this one out... strangely...
It functions well enough that I receive the email with the following message:

```
Name:
Phone number:
Email Address :
Street Address:
Managment Contact:
```

As you can see-- no data makes it through to me though.

**This is the HTML form:**

```
<td width="487" height="240" bgcolor="#1D1D1D"><form action="Contact form/processrequest.php" method="post" name="request form" target="_parent" id="request form">
              <table width="488" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
                <tr>
                  <td width="161" height="34" align="right"><label for="name" class="adf">Name </label></td>
                  <td width="303" align="left" bgcolor="#1D1D1D"><input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="50" maxlength="200" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="34" align="right" class="adf"><label for="phone">Phone Number </label></td>
                  <td align="left"><input name="Phone Number " type="text" id="Phone Number " size="50" maxlength="300" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="34" align="right" class="adf"><label for="email">Email Address </label></td>
                  <td align="left"><input name="Email Address" type="text" id="Email Address" size="50" maxlength="300" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="34" align="right" class="adf"><label for="street">Street Address </label></td>
                  <td align="left"><input name="Street Address" type="text" id="Street Address" size="50" maxlength="300" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="34" align="right" class="adf"><label for="mgmt">MGMT Contact </label></td>
                  <td align="left"><input name="Management Contact" type="text" id="Management Contact" size="50" maxlength="300" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="36" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="Send" id="Send" value="Submit" /></td>
```

**and this is the PHP:**

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name= "$name";
$phone= "$phone";
$email= "$email";
$street= "$street";
$mgmt= "$mgmt";

// Send Message
mail( "myemail@my.com", "Contact From Website",
    "Name: $name \nPhone number: $phone \nEmail Address : $email\nStreet Address:              $street\nManagment Contact: $MGMT\n",
    "From: Wearable Collections Facebook App Bin Request Form  <myemail@my.com>" );
    ?>
```

I feel like I am probably missing something very obvious--- so any help would be much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$name= "$name";
```

To get form data, you should use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Repeat for each of your form fields, and you will have a working set of data.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I used the above $_REQUEST["name"], and changed the input names (was just failing to understand which of the names I had given to my form fields were the operable ones).  Thank you so much for your time and suggestion!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's how you're getting your data.

Try it as follows.

Also, please see the security notes below.

```
<?php
    // Get Data 
    $name= $_REQUEST["name"]; // Works for both get and post, as opposed to $_GET["name"] or $_POST["name"];
    $phone= $_REQUEST["phone"];
    $email= $_REQUEST["email"];
    $street= $_REQUEST["street"];
    $mgmt= $_REQUEST["mgmt"];

    // Send Message
    mail( "myemail@my.com", "Contact From Website",
    "Name: $name \nPhone number: $phone \nEmail Address : $email\nStreet Address:              $street\nManagment Contact: $MGMT\n",
    "From: Wearable Collections Facebook App Bin Request Form  <myemail@my.com>" );
    ?>
```

More about working with PHP and Forms here:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

More about $_REQUEST here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

**IMPORTANT!!!!! Also see these articles on security, which you should learn hand-in-hand with form processing:**

http://phpsense.com/2006/php-email-injection-attacks/

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-blunders/

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't help when you're sending email.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I will read these - and I really appreciate your time!!!!

Comment: @Juhana - True, but if she's learning forms now, the next thing she'll be doing is writing to a database.  I know it's not really part of the question, and I should have given something about escaping email, but it's the same concept.

Comment: @caitlin - My pleasure!  I wish you all the luck in your learning of PHP.